# Can I add Some Katalon-Studio Console log in to Mail body?

Tags: katalon-studio

I can get the Test suite result and log in to the PDF/Html via mail, but I need to get some of those important test results into the mail body so others can see it directly. Can I do that?

I can already get the below info since Katalon has the features.

```
Host Name   abc- abcd.Direct.local
Operating System    Windows 10 64bit
Browser Chrome 76.0.3809.132
Test Suite  SmokeTestPack
Result  Passed: 5   Failed: 0   Error: 0
```

Comment: I believe katalon does not provide those features as there own, I am also hoping is there any way to do that.  :(

Comment: As I am working on some stock markets , and my work is to check whether is market open or close , so if i have these kind of opportunity in Katalon ,that would be better

Comment: There is no out of the box solution for doing this in Katalon Studio, for now.